# Want to refer to other mappers in customized mapping

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm now using Mapstruct and want to create a mapping such that, before mapping, it needs to verify that the given coordinate is in the valid area or not. If not valid, just return default value, and if valid, return that value.

This is what I have

```
public class Business { 
  ...
  Coordinate coordinate; 
}
```

```
public class BusinessDTO { 
  CoordinateDTO coordinate; 
}
```

```
public class Coordinate {
   double latitude; 
  double longitude; 
}
```

```
public class CoordinateDTO { 
  double latitude; 
  double longitude; }
```

```
@Mapping(componentModel = "spring", uses = CoordinateMapper.class)
 public interface BusinessMapper { 
  BusinessDTO toDTO(Business business);
}
```

```
default CoordinateDTO getCoordinate(Coordinate coordinate) { 
  if (valid(coordinate)) {
     return getCoordinateMapper().toDTO(coordinate);
   }
   return defaultCoordinate; 
}
```

```
@Mapping(componentModel = "spring")
 public interface CoordinateMapper { 
  CoordinateDTO toDTO(Coordinate coordinate); 
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to `getCoordinateMapper()`. One way is to use `Mappers.getMapper(CoordinateMapper.class)` but actually my coordinateMapper must refer to other mappers. Using `Mappers.getMapper(CoordinateMapper.class)` makes the referred mappers null, and causes NullPointerException.

Any suggestions how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

You use the componentModel "spring" it means that the generated classes will be a spring Bean.

You just have to inject it in the service that need to do the mapping.

Otherwise, If you dont want to inject it, then you should probably use the default component model. In the documentation they use  ([see the reference guide](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/))

```
CustomerMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( CustomerMapper.class );
```

Answer (score 0):

Mappers are stateless. So we have context objects to handle logic (like lookups, but also validation). In order not to compromise the stateless concept, you hand them via a @Context annotation.

If you put an `@AfterMapping` on top of the method, MapStruct will select that method. Make sure that MapStruct does no mapping by putting the @Mapping with ignore.

You can add any logic you want to this @Context annotated class.

```java
public class CoordinateValidator {

   @Inject
   private CoordinateMapper;

   @AfterMapping
   public void validateAndMaptoDTO(Business business, @MappingTarget BusinessDTO target) {
       if (valid(target.getCoordinate())) {
          return getCoordinateMapper().toDTO(target.getCoordinate());
        }
        return defaultCoordinate
   }

}

@Mapping(componentModel = "spring")
 public interface BusinessMapper { 

  @Mapping( target = "coordinate", ignore = true )
  BusinessDTO toDTO(Business business, @Context CoordinateValidator validator);
}
```